# How to hide alert dialog in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am currently building a loyality application within Android Studio using Firebase.

I currently have incoroporated a barcode scanner within the application. I have designed the application to have a loyalty voucher when the user has collected 10 stamps. The loyalty voucher is a QR code that will scanned then will be removed from the database therefore removing the voucher from the voucher activity.

I'm looking to hide the alert dialog but not with the onClick method.

Here is the code from my voucher class:

```
public class VoucherFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    private VoucherViewModel voucherViewModel;
    Button btVoucher1, btVoucher2, btVoucher3, btVoucher4, btVoucher5, btVoucher6, btVoucher7, btVoucher8, btVoucher9, btVoucher10;
    TextView txtVoucher;
    ImageView voucherImage;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    String userID;
    Dialog voucherDialog;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        voucherViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of( this ).get( VoucherViewModel.class );
        View root = inflater.inflate( R.layout.fragment_voucher_customer, container, false );
        btVoucher1 = root.findViewById( R.id.btVoucher1 );
        btVoucher2 = root.findViewById( R.id.btVoucher2 );
        btVoucher3 = root.findViewById( R.id.btVoucher3 );
        btVoucher4 = root.findViewById( R.id.btVoucher4 );
        btVoucher5 = root.findViewById( R.id.btVoucher5 );
        btVoucher6 = root.findViewById( R.id.btVoucher6 );
        btVoucher7 = root.findViewById( R.id.btVoucher7 );
        btVoucher8 = root.findViewById( R.id.btVoucher8 );
        btVoucher9 = root.findViewById( R.id.btVoucher9 );
        btVoucher10 = root.findViewById( R.id.btVoucher10 );

        btVoucher1.setOnClickListener( this );
        btVoucher2.setOnClickListener( this );
        btVoucher3.setOnClickListener( this );
        btVoucher4.setOnClickListener( this );
        btVoucher5.setOnClickListener( this );
        btVoucher6.setOnClickListener( this );
        btVoucher7.setOnClickListener( this );
        btVoucher8.setOnClickListener( this );
        btVoucher9.setOnClickListener( this );
        btVoucher10.setOnClickListener( this );

        txtVoucher = root.findViewById( R.id.txtVoucher );

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        userID = firebaseAuth.getUid();
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child( "Customers" ).child( userID );

        voucherViewModel.getText().observe( this, new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {

            }
        } );


        databaseReference.addValueEventListener( new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
            {
                //Check if voucher exists
                boolean voucherExists = dataSnapshot.child( "Voucher" ).exists();
                if (voucherExists == true) {
                    String voucherString = getString( R.string.voucher );
                    txtVoucher.setText( voucherString );

                    long voucherNumber = dataSnapshot.child( "Voucher" ).getChildrenCount();
                    String voucherCount = String.valueOf( voucherNumber );

                    switch (voucherCount) 
                    {
                        case "1":
                            btVoucher1.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                            break;

                        case "2":
                            btVoucher1.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                            btVoucher2.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                            break;

                        case "3":
                            btVoucher1.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                            btVoucher2.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                            btVoucher3.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                            break;

                        case "4":
                            btVoucher1.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                            btVoucher2.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                            btVoucher3.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                            btVoucher4.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                            break;

                        case "5":
                            btVoucher1.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                            btVoucher2.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                            btVoucher3.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                            btVoucher4.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                            btVoucher5.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                            break;


                        case "6":
                            btVoucher1.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                            btVoucher2.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                            btVoucher3.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                            btVoucher4.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                            btVoucher5.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                            btVoucher6.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                            break;


                        case "7":
                            btVoucher1.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                            btVoucher2.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                            btVoucher3.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                            btVoucher4.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                            btVoucher5.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                            btVoucher6.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                            btVoucher7.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                            break;

                        case "8":
                            btVoucher1.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                            btVoucher2.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                            btVoucher3.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                            btVoucher4.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                            btVoucher5.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                            btVoucher6.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                            btVoucher7.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                            btVoucher8.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                            break;

                        case "9":
                            btVoucher1.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                            btVoucher2.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                            btVoucher3.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                            btVoucher4.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                            btVoucher5.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                            btVoucher6.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                            btVoucher7.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                            btVoucher8.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                            btVoucher9.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                            break;


                        case "10":
                            btVoucher1.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                            btVoucher2.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                            btVoucher3.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                            btVoucher4.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                            btVoucher5.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                            btVoucher6.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                            btVoucher7.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                            btVoucher8.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                            btVoucher9.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                            btVoucher10.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                            break;
                    }

                } else {
                    txtVoucher.setText( "You currently have no vouchers. Please collect 10 stamps to obtain a voucher!" );
                }

                //Get QRCode
                final String qrcode = dataSnapshot.child( "qrCode" ).getValue().toString();

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                System.out.println( "The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode() );
            }
        } );


        return root;

    }




    @Override
    public void onClick(final View v)
    {
        final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());
        LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(v.getContext());
        final View view = factory.inflate(R.layout.voucher_dialog, null);
        alertDialog.setView(view);
        voucherImage = view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_imageview);
        alertDialog.setNeutralButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });



        databaseReference.addValueEventListener( new ValueEventListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                switch (v.getId())
                {
                    case R.id.btVoucher1:
                        String voucher1 = dataSnapshot.child("Voucher").child("1").getValue().toString();
                       // boolean voucherExists = dataSnapshot.child( "Voucher" ).child( "1" ).exists();
                        alertDialog.setTitle( "Voucher 1" );
                        Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(voucher1).into(voucherImage);
                        alertDialog.show();
                        break;

                    case R.id.btVoucher2:
                        String voucher2 = dataSnapshot.child("Voucher").child("2").getValue().toString();

                        alertDialog.setTitle( "Voucher 2" );
                        Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(voucher2).into(voucherImage);
                        alertDialog.show();
                        break;

                    case R.id.btVoucher3:
                        String voucher3 = dataSnapshot.child("Voucher").child("3").getValue().toString();

                        alertDialog.setTitle( "Voucher 3" );
                        Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(voucher3).into(voucherImage);
                        alertDialog.show();

                        break;

                    case R.id.btVoucher4:
                        String voucher4 = dataSnapshot.child("Voucher").child("4").getValue().toString();

                        alertDialog.setTitle( "Voucher 4" );
                        Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(voucher4).into(voucherImage);
                        alertDialog.show();
                        break;

                    case R.id.btVoucher5:
                        String voucher5 = dataSnapshot.child("Voucher").child("5").getValue().toString();

                        alertDialog.setTitle( "Voucher 5" );
                        Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(voucher5).into(voucherImage);
                        alertDialog.show();
                        break;

                    case R.id.btVoucher6:
                        String voucher6 = dataSnapshot.child("Voucher").child("6").getValue().toString();

                        alertDialog.setTitle( "Voucher 6" );
                        Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(voucher6).into(voucherImage);
                        alertDialog.show();
                        break;

                    case R.id.btVoucher7:
                        String voucher7 = dataSnapshot.child("Voucher").child("7").getValue().toString();

                        alertDialog.setTitle( "Voucher 7" );
                        Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(voucher7).into(voucherImage);
                        alertDialog.show();
                        break;

                    case R.id.btVoucher8:
                        String voucher8 = dataSnapshot.child("Voucher").child("8").getValue().toString();

                        alertDialog.setTitle( "Voucher 8" );
                        Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(voucher8).into(voucherImage);
                        alertDialog.show();
                        break;

                    case R.id.btVoucher9:
                        String voucher9 = dataSnapshot.child("Voucher").child("9").getValue().toString();

                        alertDialog.setTitle( "Voucher 9" );
                        Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(voucher9).into(voucherImage);
                        alertDialog.show();
                        break;

                    case R.id.btVoucher10:
                        String voucher10 = dataSnapshot.child("Voucher").child("10").getValue().toString();

                        alertDialog.setTitle( "Voucher 10" );
                        Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(voucher10).into(voucherImage);
                        alertDialog.show();
                        break;

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        } );
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can Hide AlertDialog if your closing requirements are met. to do so all you need to do is call **dismiss()** method on your alert dialog reference.

```
       final AlertDialog.Builder myAlertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());
       // Now to dismiss/close all you need to do is like below
       myAlertDialog.dismiss()
```

**Also**
 to close this dialog from anywhere in the same activity you can declare it as class variable.

```
      public MainActivity extends WhateverActivity{

         private AlertDialog myAlertDialog = null;


         // New Initialize it anywhere in the activity before using it
         // i.e. calling .show()

         //now dismiss it as 

         if(myAlertDialog != null && myAlertDialog.isShowing){
            myAlertDialog.dismiss()
          }

      }
```

make sure to check for null, because of this initialization

```
          private AlertDialog myAlertDialog = null;
```

I hope it is helpful.